Getting Error ' ReferenceError: Cannot access 'parsePayload' before initialization '
Here is the code :
Getting the error 'ReferenceError: Cannot access 'parsePayload' before initialization'
Please help
const express = require("express");
const { createToDo, updateToDo } = require("./types");
const { todo } = require("./db");


const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/to-do',async function(req,res){

    const createPayload = req.body;
    const parsePayload = createToDo.safeParse(parsePayload);

    if(!parsePayload.success){

        res.status(411).json({

            "msg" : "you sent the wrong input"

        })

        return;
    }

    await todo.create({
        title : createPayload.title,
        description : createPayload.description,
        completed : false
    })

    res.json({
        "msg" : "To Do Created"
    })

})

app.get('/to-do',async function(req,res){

       const todos = await todo.find();
       console.log(todos);

       res.json({
        todos
       })


})

app.put('/to-do',async function(req,res){

    const updatePayload = req.body;
    const parsePayload = updateToDo.safeParse(parsePayload);

    if(!parsePayload.success){

        res.status(411).json({

            "msg" : "you send the wrong id or input"

        })

        return;


    }

    await todo.update({
        _id : req.body.id
    },{
        completed : true
    })

    res.json({
        "msg" : "todo marked updated"
    })

})

app.listen(3000);

The parsepaylod is declared in line 13 and I am trying to use that in the same line. Still gettig error

The error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'parsePayload' before initialization occurs because you are trying to use parsePayload in its own initialization line. This happens in both the app.post and app.put routes.
Try something like this


const express = require("express");
const { createToDo, updateToDo } = require("./types");
const { todo } = require("./db");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/to-do', async function(req, res) {
    const createPayload = req.body;
    const parseResult = createToDo.safeParse(createPayload); // Corrected line

    if (!parseResult.success) {
        res.status(411).json({
            "msg": "you sent the wrong input"
        });
        return;
    }

    const validPayload = parseResult.data;

    await todo.create({
        title: validPayload.title,
        description: validPayload.description,
        completed: false
    });

    res.json({
        "msg": "To Do Created"
    });
});

app.get('/to-do', async function(req, res) {
    const todos = await todo.find();
    console.log(todos);

    res.json({
        todos
    });
});

app.put('/to-do', async function(req, res) {
    const updatePayload = req.body;
    const parseResult = updateToDo.safeParse(updatePayload); // Corrected line

    if (!parseResult.success) {
        res.status(411).json({
            "msg": "you sent the wrong id or input"
        });
        return;
    }

    const validPayload = parseResult.data;

    await todo.update({
        _id: validPayload.id
    }, {
        completed: true
    });

    res.json({
        "msg": "todo marked updated"
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});



Line 13 and Line 38: Changed const parsePayload = createToDo.safeParse(parsePayload); to const parseResult = createToDo.safeParse(createPayload); to ensure you are passing the correct payload to safeParse.
Use parseResult instead of parsePayload: Renamed the variable to parseResult to avoid confusion. After parsing, use parseResult.data to access the validated payload.
This should resolve the ReferenceError and properly parse the input payloads.

In case to know more about it, adding the following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init
